# python regex: multiline and non-greedy

Tags: python, regex

I have some text like this:

```
cc.Action = {
};

cc.FiniteTimeAction = {

};

cc.Speed = {

};
```

And I the result (list) I want is:

```
['cc.Action = {}', 'cc.FiniteTimeAction = {}', 'cc.Speed = {}']
```

And here's what I have tried:

```
input = codecs.open(self.input_file, "r", "utf-8")
content = input.read()
result = re.findall('cc\..*= {.*};', content, re.S)
for r in result:
    print r
    print '---------------'
```

And the result is:

```
[
'cc.Action = {
};

cc.FiniteTimeAction = {

};

cc.Speed = {

};'
]
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of the match seems to be `cc.` and the end of match seems to be `;` so we can use pattern:

```
'cc\.[^;]+'
```

Meaning, we match `cc.` and then match every character which is not `;` (`[]` encloses character class, `^` negates the class).

You could also use non-greedy repeat `*?`, but in this case I would say it's an overkill. The simpler the regex is the better.

To get desired input you would also have to get rid of newlines. Together I would propose:

```
result = re.findall('cc\.[^;]*;', content.replace('\n', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are using greedy search. You need to use non-greedy search with `?` operator

```
import re
print [i.replace("\n", "") for i in re.findall(r"cc\..*?{.*?}", data, re.DOTALL)]
# ['cc.Action = {}', 'cc.FiniteTimeAction = {}', 'cc.Speed = {}']
```

If you don't use `.*?`, `.*{` will match till the last `{` in the string. So, all the strings are considered as a single string. When you do non-greedy match, it matches till the first `{` from the current character.

Also, this can be done without using RegEx, like this

```
print [item.replace("\n", "") for item in data.split(";") if item]
# ['cc.Action = {}', 'cc.FiniteTimeAction = {}', 'cc.Speed = {}']
```

Just split the string based on `;` and if the current string is not empty, then replace all the `\n` (newline characters) with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

As your title suggests, the issue is greediness: `cc\..*=` matches from the beginning of the string to the *last* `=`.

You can avoid this behavior by using lazy quantifier that will try to stop at the earliest occurrence of the following character:

```
cc\..*?= {.*?};
```

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/oL4yG7.

Answer (score 0):

If you split based on `;`:

```
codes.split(';')
```

Output:

```
['cc.Action = {}', ' cc.FiniteTimeAction = {}', 'cc.Speed = {}', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'cc.Action = {\n};\n\ncc.FiniteTimeAction = {\n\n};\n\ncc.Speed = {\n\n};'.replace('\n','').split(";")
['cc.Action = {}', 'cc.FiniteTimeAction = {}', 'cc.Speed = {}', '']
```

this will work for you